# Can I match groups / optional groups using glob in Python?

Tags: python, glob

I want to be able to use the `glob` module in Python 3.9 to match filenames in a directory containing the following file names:

- "MM05_awani3_StudentA.py"
- "MM05_liu127.py"

Specifically, I want to be able to loop over all the files in a directory that fit a certain pattern. So I want to use a for loop like this:

```
for file in current_path.glob("string"):
    # do something
```

The glob pattern **"MM05_submissions/MM05_*[a-z0-9]?(_Student[A-Z]).py"** seems to work according to [DigitalOcean's glob tester tool](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tools/glob?comments=true&glob=MM05_submissions%2FMM05_%2A%5Ba-z0-9%5D%3F%28_Student%5BA-Z%5D%29.py&matches=false&tests=MM05_submissions%2FMM05_liu127.py), but I'm not getting any matches inside of Python 3.9

- Is the glob used on DigitalOcean's tester different from the one in Python?
- Can I match optional groups in Python using round brackets `()`?
- If not, should I use something like RegEx to loop over files that match a certain pattern in a directory?

Comment: Python's `glob()` function is not nearly so sophisticated. See the [`fnmatch` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/fnmatch.html#module-fnmatch) for details: there is no support for `(...)` grouping.

Answer (score 2):

You can't use `(...)` grouping, no. The `glob()` module uses the [`fnmatch` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/fnmatch.html) to do the matching, and it supports `*`, `?`, `[seq]` and `[!seq]`, nothing more.

However, `fnmatch` uses a simple pattern-to-regex conversion to test filenames. Just do the same yourself with [`os.scandir()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.scandir):

```py
import re
import os

pattern = re.compile("MM05_[a-z0-9]*(_Student[A-Z])?\.py")

for entry in os.scandir("MM05_submissions"):
    if pattern.fullmatch(entry.name):
        # name matched the pattern
```

If you need to support arbitrary depth patterns using directory names, you'll have to write something up using [`os.walk()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.walk).